# Excel POI: "We found a problem with some content in ... " when the Excel has less than 135 Rows

Tags: java, excel, scala, apache-poi, spoiwo

I have a strange behavior when creating an Excel with **POI**.

Whenever I have less than ~135 rows I cannot open the Excel, with the following Exception:

[image: excel-alert]

If I have more rows I can open the Excel without any problems.

Here is the Code, how I create the Worksheet:

```
val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
try {
    wb = createWorkbook()
    wb.writeToOutputStream(out)
    out.flush()
    out.toByteArray
} finally IOUtils.closeQuietly(out)
```

I use a *Scala* wrapper [spoiwo](https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo).

Here is the code `writeToOutputStream`:

```
override def writeToOutputStream[T <: OutputStream](stream: T): T =
  try {
    convertAsXlsx().write(stream)
    stream
  } finally {
    stream.flush()
    stream.close()
  }

def convertAsXlsx(): XSSFWorkbook = convertWorkbook(workbook)
```

I added an Issue here: https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo/issues/44

Comment: Where is the `wb.close()` in your code? Ary you closing the workbook anywhere else?

Comment: So just to be precise. the above code results in a document with that error? (just asking: maybe it is just not valid to create an "empty" sheet like this)?

Comment: @deHaar I adjusted my question - it does not seem that the Workbook is closed by `spoiwo`

Comment: @GhostCat that is correct - the only difference between working and not working is just the number of rows - and it is not random

Comment: @pme I only know how to properly create a workbook in Java, Scala seems to use slightly different methods. In Java, I have to (1) create a `FileOutputStream` with the full path of the workbook, (2) write the workbook with that (`workbook.write(fileOutputStream)`, (3) close and flush the stream and then close the workbook.

Comment: I would create a failing file (<= 135 lines) and a working one (> 135 lines). Unzip both .xlsx files and compare their content. This will give you at least an idea which part might contain the error. Also check if both .xlsx are valid .zip files, this somehow seem to be a truncated file case. If this is part of an web application and you forward the bytes to a browser, please also try to directly save to a FileOutputStream just to verify that the error doesn't occur later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not related to `poi`.

**Removing** `play-html-compressor` fixed the problem.

It seems that this `sbt` plugin has a bug.

(see [play-html-compressor](https://github.com/mohiva/play-html-compressor))